# JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `"react": "16.11.0",`. On old source code using `.js` extension but after I changed to `.tsx` and got error as below on Visual Code.

```
JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property
```

[image]

Any help!

Comment: By adding `yarn add @types/react` resolved the issue.